# How do I prevent Spark from automatically adding time in date column?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pandas df that contains a date column. The date is correctly formatted as y-m-d without time. When I convert it into a Spark df using `df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)`, the date format changes to this: https://i.imgur.com/HFafmXw.png

How do I remove the time from the date?

Comment: `to_date($"Date")` can be used to only retrieve date from datetime values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either **`to_date`**(preferred),**`cast to date`**,`date_format()`,`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`  functions.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("2020-04-15 00:00:00",)],["Date"])
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#using to_date function preferred
df.withColumn("Date", to_date(col("Date"))).show()

#casting to date
df.withColumn("Date", col("Date").cast("date")).show()

#using date_format function
df.withColumn("Date", date_format(col("Date"),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show()

#using from_unixtime and unix_timestamp functions
df.withColumn("Date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("Date"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
#+----------+
#|      Date|
#+----------+
#|2020-04-15|
#+----------+
```

Comment: can you do me a favor? Can you can upvote my question?

Comment: For some reason, I was not allowed to ask any more questions. According to the help section, this may be due to unhelpful questions. That's why I asked. Thank you.